# css circular image anchor too large

Tags: css, image, background, anchor

I'm currently displaying a users profile picture in php and if they click on it, then it takes them through to their own profile. The image displays correctly and the link works, but the area of the link extends way beyond the picture and over a link nearby. How would I go about reducing the area of the anchor?

```
    <?php }    if ($searchuser == $username)
 { ?>
                                    <a href="profile.php">
                                        <?php } ?>

                                            <div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $profilepic; ?> ')" class="user-pic"></div>
                                            <?php if ($searchuser == $username)
 {?>
                                    </a>
div.user-pic {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 0.09em solid white;
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

php

```
<?php } 
    $show_user_link = false;
    if ($searchuser == $username) { 
        $show_user_link = true;
    }
?>

<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $profilepic; ?>')" class="user-pic">
    <?php if( $show_user_link ): ?>
        <a class="user-link" href="profile.php">
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

css

```
div.user-pic {
    position: relative;
}

a.user-link {
    height: 125px;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

You put the anchor in within the div tag and then you could make div's position relative and anchor's width to 100%.

PS: You could try to use something like

```
<?php if(true): ?>
<strong> some html </strong>
<?php endif; ?>
```

when mixing php and html to make your code more readable.

--- EDIT

Ok, I understand, see if the new code is more helpfull now, the only thing I think that could go wrong is the height of the anchor in case it isnt fixed to 125px, say me if you have problems with it.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't explain myself correctly. The picture is displayed for anyone that wants to view it, but if the user is looking at their own picture, they can click on the link. So the link condition is only impacted by the if statement - the picture is always displayed. I think moving the link inside would result in only the user being able to view their own picture.

Comment: did the new edited answer work to fix your problem? If not where did it fail?